# How do I use fish shell functions in abbreviations?

Tags: git, fish

Say I have the following `git_branch_name` function:

```
$ echo git_branch_name
master

$ git pull origin (git_branch_name) // Pulls origin master
```

How could I use that function within an abbreviation?

Here is what I have tried:

```
abbr -a ggl git pull origin (git_branch_name)
```

Unfortunately this interpolates `(git_branch_name)` during the definition of the abbreviation.

Comment: Sure? Because I just tried `abbr -s` and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to defer the substitution just quote it when defining the abbreviation:

```
abbr -a ggl 'git pull origin (git_branch_name)'
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. This being said, I was hoping to have the function interpolate when expanding the abbreviation. I posted a follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57919964/can-fish-shell-interpolate-functions-when-expanding-to-their-full-form