# Can fish shell interpolate functions when expanding to their full form?

Tags: git, fish

Given the following abbreviation, where `git_branch_name` returns the current git branch name:

```
abbr -a ggl 'git pull origin (git_branch_name)'
```

Is there a way to have the the function interpolate when the abbreviation is expanded?

```sh
# This is what the abbreviation expands to
$ git pull origin (git_branch_name)

# This is the expansion I am looking for
$ git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not yet possible for an abbreviation to run code when it expands. I expect we'll add this capability before long.

Comment: Should I open a GitHub issue for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function instead:

```
function ggl
    commandline 'git pull origin '(git_branch_name)
end
```

or even a keybinding (Alt + g)

```
bind \eg 'commandline -i "git pull origin"(git_branch_name)'
```

Answer (score 1):

This capability now exists in fish! For [Pierre Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1532/pierre-spring)'s specific example, in fish 3.2.2, the abbreviation

```
abbr -a ggl git pull origin (git_branch_name)
```

will expand to

```
git pull origin master
```

The **generalized** case looks like this:

1. Create a custom function foo.fish that returns bar

   ```
   function foo
   echo bar
   end
   ```
2. Add an abbreviation "rtb" that, when it expands, pipes in the result of the function foo

   ```
   abbr -a rtb echo raise the (foo)
   ```
3. Now, entering `rtb` on the command line will:

   - expand to the command `echo raise the bar`
   - return the result `raise the bar`